# Proof of Quotient Theorem for Topological Groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm reading *Topology, An Introduction With Application To Topological Groups* by McCarty. In Chapter 5, he states the Quotient Theorem for Topological Groups:

> Each morphism $f: G \to G'$ of topological groups possesses a unique factorization $f = i \circ r \circ q$ into topological morphisms, where $q$ is a quotient, $r$ is an algebraic isomorphism, and $i$ is an inclusion. The quotient $q$ is always open, $i$ is open iff $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is open in $G'$, and $r$ is a topological isomorphism iff $f$ is open onto its image.

My illustration:

[image]

I am trying to complete the proof of this theorem, which is mostly stated without proof in the text. I have managed every part ok *except* that I cannot figure out the entire "iff" at the end, namely, to prove that if $r$ is a topological isomorphism, then $f$ is open onto its image.

Here's what I have so far: Assume that $r$ is a topological isomorphism; it is therefore an open function. I know that $q$ is open, because every quotient map from a topological group $G$ to a coset space $G/H$ must be open. We are given that $i$ is open iff $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is open in $G'$. So, I can see that $f = i \circ r \circ q$ will be open if $r$ is open AND $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is open in $G'$. But I don't know why $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ should be open in $G'$ without already knowing that $f$ is open.

I'd appreciate any hints. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't "$f$ is open onto its image" mean precisely that $r\circ q$ is open? (Since you already know that $f$ factors as a map of sets.) Otherwise I don't know what distinction that term would be drawing from just "$f$ is open". (No trouble with the "onto", since $f$ is always onto its image, of course.)

Comment: McCarty says that r is an *algebraic* isomorphism. You, however, assume r to be a *topological* isomorphism, a stronger statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\img}{\operatorname{img}}\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}$

As @Eric Nathan Stucky said, $f$ being open onto its image is **not** the same as $f$ being open.

Denote by $p=r\circ q$ the map projecting $G$ onto its image under $f$.

Since $G/\ker(f)$ is a topological quotient, the map $r:G/\ker(f) \rightarrow \img(f)$ is continuous, since it is induced from the universal property applied to $p$. Thus $r$ is a topological isomorphism if and only if $r$ is open.

Since $q$ is open, if $r$ is open, so is $p$ (which is what is meant by saying that $f$ is open onto its image). Conversely, if $p$ is open, we want to deduce that $r$ is open. So take an open $U \subseteq G/\ker(f)$. Since $q$ is an surjective continuous map, the preimage $q^{-1}(U) \subseteq G$ is open and $q(q^{-1}(U))=U$. Now we are done, noting that $p(q^{-1}(U)) = rq(q^{-1}(U)) = r(U)$ is open.

Comment: Thanks Jonas and @eric-nathan-stucky, I didn't know why McCarty would say "$f$ is open onto its image" when he could have just said "$f$ is open." This interpretation didn't occur to me at all. Problem solved!